# Why doesn't AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode return RefreshToken

Tags: c#, azure, azure-ad-b2c, microsoft-identity-platform

In this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-apps#web-apis) it gives a complete flow for a web application that calls a web API:

> 1. The web application executes a policy and the user completes the user experience.
> 2. Azure AD B2C returns an (OpenID Connect) id_token and an authorization code to the browser.
> 3. The browser posts the id_token and authorization code to the redirect URI.
> 4. The web server validates the id_token and sets a session cookie.
> 5. The web server asks Azure AD B2C for an access_token by providing it with the authorization code, application client ID, and
>      client credentials.
> 6. The access_token and refresh_token are returned to the web server.
> 7. The web API is called with the access_token in an authorization header.
> 8. The web API validates the token.
> 9. Secure data is returned to the web application.

Looking at 6. and using the code in the Azure-Samples repository [active-directory-b2c-dotnet-webapp-and-webapi](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnet-webapp-and-webapi)
, I cannot get the line

```
AuthenticationResult result = await confidentialClient.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode(Globals.Scopes, notification.Code).ExecuteAsync();
```

to return a refresh_token. It returns an IdToken and AccessToken but no RefreshToken.
[image: screenshot of breakpoint result]

By using my browser and Postman and following the steps in this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-oidc#send-authentication-requests) with the same B2C tenant and application I **do** get the refresh token as expected.

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45438804/azure-ad-b2c-openid-connect-refresh-token) is similar to mine and the [blog post](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2016/07/25/controlling-a-web-apps-session-duration-2/) mentioned in one of the answers provides a work around to the symptom of not having a refresh token but my question remains:

How can I get `AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode` to return a refresh_token?

Answer (score 1):

To get refresh token, your application should append **offline_access** as scope.

You mentioned like [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-oidc#send-authentication-requests) msdn able to return you refresh token. It is because request already contain offline_access scope

```
&scope=openid%20offline_access
```

To get refresh token from [active-directory-b2c-dotnet-webapp-and-webapi](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnet-webapp-and-webapi). You need to update [Global.cs](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnet-webapp-and-webapi/blob/7f39714b88016b2e234dda8c56539bab6635dcb7/TaskWebApp/Utils/Globals.cs) Scopes filed to include offline_access

```
public static string[] Scopes = new string[] { ReadTasksScope, WriteTasksScope, "offline_access" };
```

Comment: I had tried this previously and still get an error: _MSAL always sends the scopes 'openid profile offline_access'._

Answer (score 1):

The [offline_access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-oidc) scope is optional for web apps. It **indicates that your app needs a refresh token** for long-lived access to resources.

Go to web.config add below:

```
 <add key ="api:OfflineAccessScope" value="offline_access "/>
```

And in Global.cs :

```
public static string OfflineAccessScope = ApiIdentifier + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["api:OfflineAccessScope"];
public static string[] Scopes = new string[] { ReadTasksScope, WriteTasksScope, OfflineAccessScope};
```

Then the `Globals.Scopes` in `AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode` will return refresh token.

Comment: I had tried this previously and still get an error: MSAL always sends the scopes 'openid profile offline_access'.

Comment: makes sense thank you; with these the access_token didn't show the offline scope so I also added these to Startup_Auth Scope = $"openid profile offline_access {Globals.ReadTasksScope} {Globals.WriteTasksScope} {Globals.OfflineTasksScope}" and the access_token shows scp: "demo.offline_access demo.read demo.write", but the request does not return the refresh token

Comment: Is it still valid, now the access token returned by outlook doesn't seems to be jwt?