# Azure WebApp-WebAPI ->Grant Type authorization_code doesn't return RefreshToken

Tags: azure, authorization, access-token, azure-ad-b2c, refresh-token

I've followed this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58407041/why-doesnt-acquiretokenbyauthorizationcode-return-refreshtoken) in relation to this [example](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnet-webapp-and-webapi) and made the additions to the portal and code as suggested:

Portal: Web API - Expose an API - Add Scope for "offline_access" (also tried with format "demo.offline_access"); Web App added "offline_access" permission

Code: Added offline_access to Start_Auth.cs, Global.cs and both Web.config files.

I make my request for accessToken and refreshToken as per [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow) with:

```
var ClientID = "XXXX";
            var BaseURL = "https://XXX.b2clogin.com/XXX.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/token?p=B2C_1_signinsignoutpolicy";
            var ClientSecret = "XXX";
            string redirectUri = "https://XXX.azurewebsites.net/api/GetAccessToken";
            var content = new StringContent(
              "&grant_type=authorization_code"+
              "&client_id="+ClientID+
              "&scope=" + "https://XXX.onmicrosoft.com/api/demo.read https://XXX.onmicrosoft.com/api/demo.write https://XXX.onmicrosoft.com/api/offline_access" +
              "&code="+authCode+
              "&redirect_uri=" + redirectUri+
              "&client_secret=" + ClientSecret,
              Encoding.UTF8,
              "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

            var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(BaseURL, content);
            var output = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

output returns access_token but no refresh token. When looking at the claims of the access_token, scope (scp) correctly shows offline_access demo.read demo.write

What am I missing to get refresh token?

[EDIT}
Here's postman result:
[image]
JWT for access token received:
[image]
WebApp API Permissions:
[image]
WebAPI - Expose an API:
[image]

Code changes:
Both WebApp and WebAPI Web.config scopes:

```
<add key="api:ReadScope" value="demo.read" />
<add key="api:WriteScope" value="demo.write" />
<add key="api:OfflineScope" value="offline_access" />
```

TaskWebApp Globals.cs scope addition:

```
// API Scopes
    public static string ApiIdentifier = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["api:ApiIdentifier"];
    public static string ReadTasksScope = ApiIdentifier + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["api:ReadScope"];
    public static string WriteTasksScope = ApiIdentifier + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["api:WriteScope"];
    public static string OfflineTasksScope = ApiIdentifier + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["api:OfflineScope"];
    public static string[] Scopes = new string[] { ReadTasksScope, WriteTasksScope, OfflineTasksScope };
```

TaskWebApp Startup.Auth.cs scope addition at ConfigureAuth:

```
// Specify the scope by appending all of the scopes requested into one string (separated by a blank space)
                Scope = $"openid profile offline_access {Globals.ReadTasksScope} {Globals.WriteTasksScope} {Globals.OfflineTasksScope}"
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: I have tried with postman and works perfectly for me. Could you make sure you have encountered same problem on postman too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`https://XXX.onmicrosoft.com/api/offline_access` is a permission you customized in your web api app. It's not for getting a refresh token.

You just need to use `offline_access` here.

```
"&scope=" + "https://XXX.onmicrosoft.com/api/demo.read https://XXX.onmicrosoft.com/api/demo.write offline_access"
```

Comment: Thank you @Allen Wu , I had that already before customing offline_access and didn't work (// Specify the scope by appending all of the scopes requested into one string (separated by a blank space)
                Scope = $"openid profile offline_access {Globals.ReadTasksScope} {Globals.WriteTasksScope}"), where should I add it in the example (please see posted code setup). Should I also make any changes in the portal?

Comment: @SergioSolorzano Remove the offline_access permission under your WebAPI on Azure Portal. You can also try to use `"&scope=" + "offline_access"` only to see if you can get the refresh token. If you can get it, try with `"&scope=" + "https://XXX.onmicrosoft.com/api/demo.read https://XXX.onmicrosoft.com/api/demo.write offline_access"` after you remove the offline_access permission.